# Scale down image in VUEJS Component

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have the following VUEJS template code, its a chatbot for an image generation software,

```
<template>
  <!-- Main container for the entire chat interface -->
  <v-container ref="chatContainer" >
    <!-- Container for displaying chat messages -->
    <v-row class="messages-container" >
      <v-col cols="14">
        <!-- Styling for the messages -->
        <div class="pa-4 messages"  >
          <!-- Loop through messages in reverse order to display newest at the bottom -->
          <div v-for="(message, index) in reversedChats" :key="index" class="my-2 d-flex flex-column">
            <!-- Conditional styling for user and bot messages -->
            <div :class="['message-chip', message.sender === 'user' ? 'question' : 'response']">
              <!-- Display avatar for user message -->
              <img v-if="message.sender === 'user'" src="../../assets/user.png" class="avatar user-avatar">
              <!-- Display avatar for bot response -->
              <img v-if="message.sender !== 'user'" src="../../assets/bot.png" class="avatar bot-avatar">
               <!-- Display message content -->
              <div v-if="!message.isImage" v-html="message.content"></div>
              <!-- Render image if message is an image -->
              <img v-else :src="message.content" alt="Generated Image">
              <div v-if="!message.imagePrompt" v-html="message.imagePrompt"></div>
            
              <!-- Display source buttons if sources are available -->
              <div v-if="message.sources && message.sources.length" class="source-buttons">
                <!-- Loop through sources and display buttons for each -->
                <v-btn
                  v-for="(source, sIndex) in message.sources"
                  :key="`source-${sIndex}`"
                  small
                  class="source-button"
                  @click="sourceAction(source.url)"
                >
                  {{ source.title }}
                </v-btn>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
```

the backend always generates images in 1024x1024, and I want to scale them down, but I havent been able to. If I add a class to the img tag with max with= 50%, this is totally ignored.  I also tried inline styles and they are removed also.

I dont know what else to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Vuetify? You can use `v-img` of Vuetify

You can read document here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/images/ and https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-img/

Example what you want, you can try:

```
<v-img
    width="50%"
    :aspect-ratio="1/1"
    cover
    src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/parallax/material.jpg" // link your image
></v-img>
```